# Set up Gtk development on windows

Tags: gtk, mingw, gtkmm, msys2

I want to compile my program that uses Gtk(mm) for windows. So I have set up MinGW and MSys2 and downloaded a bunch of stuff via pacman.

Now when I try to compile my program using the following command:

```
g++ Patte.cpp -o Patte -L/opt/lib `pkg-config gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

The compiler fails reporting that it cannot find the following file that I include:

```
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
```

Can someone maybe help me with this error? I would be very grateful for your help.

Edit: This line occurs after several includes that reference gstreamer, gtkmm and glib - so those seem to pass.

Comment: I'm not sure which of the three MSYS2 toolchains you are using.  Could you post the full output of these commands?  `which g++`  and `echo $MSYSTEM`

Comment: $ echo $MSYSTEM
MINGW64

Comment: $ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.3.0

Comment: And the command literally just fails reporting the file was not found.

Comment: You didn't run `which g++`

Comment: Oh sorry ^^ Here it is: $ which g++
/usr/bin/g++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in the MinGW-w64 64-bit shell but you didn't install the toolchain yet.

You should run:

```
pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-toolchain mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm3
```

Comment: I needed to change mingw-w64-gtkmm3 to mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm3